# When a file is deleted, write this to logfile (BATCH)

Tags: batch-file, logging, delete-file

Supposedly I want to delete logfiles from the C:\ drive. (XXX-Log1.log XXX-Log2.log)

Question: if a file is deleted (I'm just using the `del /f /q C:\*.log` command), there's obviously no output.

How can I write output to a logfile when a file is deleted and only then? I know for writing to a logfile you can use `>>"D:\What\Ever\Deleted.log"`, but I'd like to have displayed which files were deleted, if any.

Answer (score 1):

If the folder does not have any subdirectories, then this will work:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions
del /s "c:\folder\*.log" >file.log
pause
```

Comment: I will try this tomorrow. But typically, there are subdirectories. Any idea what to do if that's the case? Thanks.

Comment: foxidrive, I've tested this solution, with no subdirectories, but the logfile came up blank. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You are correct. I forgot to append the /s switch. I've tested here (with /s /f /q), and also a subdirectory. File got deleted and logged. I'll test if it also works if there are several subdirs present. 

Peculiar though that it only gets logged when using the /s switch?

Comment: All files matching the filespec in all subdirectories will be deleted.  If you can use that then it's the simplest and fastest method.  If not then you'll need to use a loop and delete/log each file individually.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a vbscript you can use to monitor a folder for deletion events. This might do what you want. Just call it with cscript like `cscript /nologo monitorfolder.vbs` You'll need to edit it to monitor in your path. I just used my C:\temp folder for testing.

```
MonitorFolder()

Function MonitorFolder()
intInterval = "2"
strDrive = "C:" 
strFolder = "\\temp\\"
strComputer = "." 
Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFS.CreateTextFile("C:\temp\Deleted.log")
Set objWMIService = GetObject( "winmgmts:" & _ 
    "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _ 
    strComputer & "\root\cimv2" )
strQuery =  _
    "Select * From __InstanceOperationEvent" _
    & " Within " & intInterval _
    & " Where Targetinstance Isa 'CIM_DataFile'" _
    & " And TargetInstance.Drive='" & strDrive & "'" _
    & " And TargetInstance.Path='" & strFolder & "'"
Set colEvents = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery (strQuery) 
WScript.Echo "Monitoring events...[Ctl-C] to end"
Do 

    Set objEvent = colEvents.NextEvent()
    Set objTargetInst = objEvent.TargetInstance

    Select Case objEvent.Path_.Class 
        Case "__InstanceDeletionEvent" 
            objFile.WriteLine(objTargetInst.Name)
    End Select 
Loop
End Function
```